# All the possible path to reach bottom of a m*n matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, matrix, depth-first-search

```
public static int printStepsToReachBottom(int rows, int columns, String[] array) {
    if (rows == 1) {
        array[0] = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < columns - 1; i++) {
            array[0] += "H";
        }
        return 1;
    }
    if (columns == 1) {
        array[0] = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++) {
            array[0] += "V";
        }
        return 1;
    }
    String[] temporary = new String[1000];
    int k = 0;
    int firstTypeMove = printStepsToReachBottom(rows - 1, columns, array);
    for (int i = 0; i < firstTypeMove; i++) {
        temporary[k] = array[i] + "V";
        k++;
    }
    int secondTypeMove = printStepsToReachBottom(rows, columns - 1, array);
    for (int i = 0; i < secondTypeMove; i++) {
        temporary[k] = array[i] + "H";
        k++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < secondTypeMove + firstTypeMove; i++) {
        array[i] = temporary[i];
    }
    return secondTypeMove + firstTypeMove;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array = new String[1000];
    int outputSize = printStepsToReachBottom(2, 2, array);
    for (int i = 0; i < outputSize; i++) {
        System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how this code snippet is working. I didn't understand the logic. It prints All the possible paths to reach the bottom of an m*n matrix
It prints "HV" and "VH" for the 2x2 matrix. Help me.

Comment: **_It prints "HV" and "VH" for the 2x2 matrix_** I don't see a 2x2 matrix in your code. Also": what are you trying to do ? Are you familiar with recursion ?  Where is this code taken from ?

Comment: @c0der I have just taken an example of (2,2matrix) to explain what it is going to do. but the code works for all m*n matrices. It prints All the possible paths to reach the bottom of the given matrix (H means horizontal moves and V means vertical moves) and we have to print the correct sequence of each path. And yes I'm familiar with recursion.

Comment: Side note: you can print part of the array by `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOf(array, outputSize)));`

Answer (score 1):

You can breakdown the code into three parts;

```
if (rows == 1) {
    array[0] = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < columns - 1; i++) {
        array[0] += "H";
    }
    return 1;
}
if (columns == 1) {
    array[0] = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < rows - 1; i++) {
        array[0] += "V";
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This part is the end case of the recursion. It says that there is no more rows or columns to go and return an array with size 1 either containing H(or H's) or V(or V's)

```
String[] temporary = new String[1000];
int k = 0;
int firstTypeMove = printStepsToReachBottom(rows - 1, columns, array);
for (int i = 0; i < firstTypeMove; i++) {
    temporary[k] = array[i] + "V";
    k++;
}
int secondTypeMove = printStepsToReachBottom(rows, columns - 1, array);
for (int i = 0; i < secondTypeMove; i++) {
    temporary[k] = array[i] + "H";
    k++;
}
```

The second part executes the recursion through both H and V directions for any given step which adds two more recursive calls to the stack (Although, in execution it performs a depth-first search rather than a breadth-first one, the idea is easier to grasp that way)

```
int secondTypeMove = printStepsToReachBottom(rows, columns - 1, array);
for (int i = 0; i < secondTypeMove; i++) {
    temporary[k] = array[i] + "H";
    k++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < secondTypeMove + firstTypeMove; i++) {
    array[i] = temporary[i];
}
return secondTypeMove + firstTypeMove;
```

And the last part collects the outputs from both H and V directions into the global array and returns the number of outputs to the upper stack.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simpler recursive Depth First Search that will do the same:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main   {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            dfsPrintAllPathesTopToBottom(3,3);
    }

    //performs dfs to map all possible paths on a rows x columns matrix
    //from top left to bottom right by moving right (R) or down (R)
    public static void dfsPrintAllPathesTopToBottom(int rows, int columns){
        List<String> path = new ArrayList<>();
        dfsPrintAllPathesTopToBottom(0, 0,rows,columns,path);
    }

    public static void dfsPrintAllPathesTopToBottom(int row, int col, int rows, int columns,  List<String> path ){

        if(row == rows -1  && col == columns -1){//bottom left reached
            System.out.println(path);
            return;
        }

        //move right
        int newCol = col +1;
        if(newCol < columns  ){
            List<String>newPath = new ArrayList<>(path);
            newPath.add("R");//or newPath.add("H")
            dfsPrintAllPathesTopToBottom(row, newCol, rows, columns, newPath);
        }

        //move down
        int newRow = row +1;
        if(newRow < rows ){
            List<String>newPath = new ArrayList<>(path);
            newPath.add("D"); //or newPath.add("V")
            dfsPrintAllPathesTopToBottom(newRow, col, rows, columns, new ArrayList<>(newPath));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an easy implementation. Thanks, You are a life saviour.